# What are the actual current total count and per capita count of interracial rape?

Tags: criminology, sexual-abuse, racism, race

There are many pictures floating over the internet which says Black on White rape is so much more than White on Black rape. How true is this? **Is this true even now?**

[image]

Source: https://bjs.ojp.gov/content/pub/pdf/cvus08.pdf

[image]

Source: Table 42 of

https://bjs.ojp.gov/content/pub/pdf/cvus0302.pdf
https://bjs.ojp.gov/content/pub/pdf/cvus0402.pdf
https://bjs.ojp.gov/content/pub/pdf/cvus0502.pdf
https://bjs.ojp.gov/content/pub/pdf/cvus0602.pdf

---

**If this is false or misleading or obsolete data what are the real numbers of total Black on White rape and White on Black rape as of current times, say from 2017 to 2022?**

**What are the actual current total count and per capita count of interracial rape?**

Comment: What is the notable claim here? You appear to be asking for crime statistics which would not be on topic.

Comment: some of those table indicate around 20 000 rape by black man and then than it is an "*Estimate is based on about 10 or fewer sample cases.". 0% in 20 000 is an approximation and not actually 0 case